# Where is the denoiser?

Tags: rendering, render-layers, denoise

Can someone tell me where this denoiser is? I know it's in the renderlayetab, but i can't find it i can only find view
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are running Blender 2.75. [The denoiser was added in 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles#Denoising), so you'll need to download a newer version.